# Error when sending special characters using OutputStream when the charset is UTF-8

Tags: java, character-encoding

I am creating a simple service using HttpServer. The service works correctly when I use strings without special characters.

```
public static void main (String arg []) throws Exception {
    HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(serverPort), 0);
    server.createContext("/notification", new MyHandler());
    server.setExecutor(null); // creates a default executor
    server.start();
}

static class MyHandler implements HttpHandler {
    public void handle(HttpExchange t) throws IOException {
        String response;

        response = "with special characters éáã "; // it doesn't work
        response = "without special characters"; // it works!

        String encoding = "UTF-8";

        System.out.println(response);

        t.getResponseHeaders().set("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=" + encoding);

        t.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.length());
        byte[] bytes = response.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        OutputStream os = t.getResponseBody();
        os.write(bytes);
        os.flush();

        os.close();
    }
}
```

When my UTF-8 string has special characters, it return this error:

java.io.IOException: too many bytes to write to stream
at sun.net.httpserver.FixedLengthOutputStream.write(FixedLengthOutputStream.java:76)
at java.io.FilterOutputStream.write(FilterOutputStream.java:97)
at sun.net.httpserver.PlaceholderOutputStream.write(ExchangeImpl.java:439)
at InternalServer$MyHandler.handle(InternalServer.java:86)
at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:79)
at sun.net.httpserver.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:83)
at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:82)
at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange$LinkHandler.handle(ServerImpl.java:675)
at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:79)
at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange.run(ServerImpl.java:647)
at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$DefaultExecutor.execute(ServerImpl.java:158)
at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Dispatcher.handle(ServerImpl.java:431)
at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Dispatcher.run(ServerImpl.java:396)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the problem.

```
 t.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.length());
```

The second parameter to `sendResponseHeaders` must be the exact size of the content you are going to send **in bytes**.  But you are passing the length of a string **in characters**.

In UTF-8, any character that is larger than U+0080 will be encoded as 2 or more bytes.  Your second example string contains characters that are larger than U+0080, so when it is encoded in UTF-8, the character count and byte count are different.  You will be setting the incorrect content length in the response header

It looks like the output stream provided by `HttpExchange` is checking that you do not send more bytes than you set in the response header.  (That would be an HTTP protocol violation.)

Solution:

```
 ...
 byte[] bytes = response.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
 t.sendResponseHeaders(200, bytes.length);
 ...
```

It is also possible to pass `0` as the content length.  That will cause the body to be sent using [chunked transfer encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding).